# Conditional on data counting (Excel)

Tags: excel

I have some data like it which cannot change it.

```
Account  Balance
1        <10
2         20
3        100
4         30
5         40
6         50
7         60
```

I need to make a simple excel program to count the balance range.

```
Range  Number of count
<10 
10  
10-100
```

In the range of 10, I can count by use the formula

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B8,10)
```

But I do not know how to count "<10", since "<10" is a element in balance, I cannot change it.

Did anyone can help me to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=COUNTIF(C3:C12,"*<10*")
```

---

use this formula. and let me know